# AS3 Flash checkbox in datagrid

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have successfully fill the grid from mysql database using service.
I have datagrid like this

```
 Col_1     Col_2    Col_3    Col_4
[Chekbox]  value    value    value
[Chekbox]  value    value    value
[Chekbox]  value    value    value
[Chekbox]  value    value    value
```

NOTE : plid is value for checkboxes

```
for (varName in returnObj) {
var plid                = int   (returnObj[varName]["plid"]);
var varState            = String(returnObj[varName]["state"]);
var varCity             = String(returnObj[varName]["city"]); 

 arrDP.push({        //arrDP is array defined
  //Column          Value
  Select          : plid, 
  State           : varState,
  City            : varCity
});

var dp:DataProvider              = new DataProvider(arrDP);
var select:DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("Select");
var state :DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("State");
var city  :DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("City");    
dg.dataProvider                  = dp; //dg IS DATAGRID NAME AND dp IS DATAPROVIDER
}
```

value for chekboxes is : 1 & 0. where 1 mean TRUE(selected) and 0 mean FALSE(not selected).
my question is how to show checkboxes to be SELECTED for value 1??
as checkbox need an event to be occur for state change.
I am using the following cellrender class.

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=234416

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking up your problem first before asking this question? In actionscript, a checkbox is selected, not checked :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the `CheckBox` instance.
2. Check if the `plid` is 1 or 0 and toggle the checkbox accordingly.

Like so:

```
//The checkbox instance variable name in this example is cb
cb.selected = plid == 1 ? true : false;
```

The `selected` getter/setter indicates if the `CheckBox` is to be displayed as checked or not.

Read more about that here:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/LabelButton.html#selected